# Split And Replace Simple String Manipulation

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for url in self.urls:
    f.write(url+"\n")
    f.flush()
```

The URL looks like:

```
http://www.site.com/Test-Title/data/78945613
```

I'm trying to save another version which is grabbing the code "78945613"
and adding to end of this URL:

```
www.site.com/buy/id/78945613
```

I was able to grab the code using:

```
for url in self.urls:
    f.write(url.split("/")[-1]+"\n")
    f.flush()
```

But it's only the code it's missing `"www.site.com/buy/id/"` how can I add `"www.site.com/buy/id/"` at start and only then save?

Comment: Python has a module to parse urls properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
strs = "www.site.com/buy/id/"
for url in self.urls:
    f.write(strs + url.split("/")[-1] + "\n")
    f.flush()
```

Another alternative is string formatting:

```
f.write("www.site.com/buy/id/{}\n".format(url.split("/")[-1]))
```

Comment: `f.write("site..." + url.split("/")[-1] + "\n")` will this work?

Comment: I'd go for: `url.rpartition('/')[2]`